# How to fill an array with findByIdAndUpdate in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am currently trying to do an Algo to complete a table of 1. My table is defined by :

```
const content = new Array(content_size)
 
for (let i = 0; i < content_size; i++) {
     content[i] = new Array(content_size)
     content[i].fill(0)
}
```

with content_size = 100.

What I would like to do is with the findByIdAndUpdate() function of Mongoose, fill this table that is in Mongo, only with 10

Answer (score 0):

`findByIdAndUpdate` is for one document. For multiple documents you can use `update` with multi flag true.

update takes 3 arguments

1. Query
2. Update
3. Options

*here query selectors works the same as in find().*

```
db.COLLECTION_NAME.update({}, {$set: {fill: 1}}, { multi: true })
```

for more information check : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

I hope this solves your problem.